# Rails Voting Ajax(acts_as_votable)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am currently on a project.I am using acts_as_votable gem for the like system. Instead of button I am using glypicons. Everything works fine, But the problem is when I click like, every Post is liked, But I want only the selected Post to be liked.

In post_controller:

```
def upvote
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @post.upvote_from current_user
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :back }
        format.js
     end
end
```

In index.html.erb:

```
<div class='votee'>        
            <%= render partial: 'vote', locals: {:@post => post}%>
        </div>
```

In the Partial _vote.html.erb I have

```
<small class="likecount-<%= @post.id %>"><%= pluralize(@post.get_upvotes.size, 'like', 'like\'s' )%>&nbsp;</small>
<% if current_user.voted_up_on? @post %>
<%= link_to like_post_path(@post), class: "like", method: :put, remote: true do%>
    <i class="fa fa-heart fa-lg"  style="color:#900603;"></i>&nbsp;
<% end -%>
```

And in the upvote.js.erb

```
$('.votee').html('<%= j render partial: 'vote'%>');
$('.likecount-<%= @post.id %>').html('<%= j pluralize(@post.get_upvotes.size, 'like', 'like\'s' )%>');
```

The Routes are workin fine.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: After clicking the button, observe the logs inside your `rails server` terminal. Sometimes you'll get hints from there.

Comment: I don't get any errors in my logs, It works fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error has to be something to do with...

```
<%= render partial: 'vote', locals: {:@post => post} %>
```

... it should be ...

```
<%= render partial: 'vote', locals: {post: post} %>
```

--

The partial should get rid of `@post` and have `post` instead:

```
<small class="likecount-<%= post.id %>"><%= pluralize(post.get_upvotes.size, 'like', 'like\'s' )%>&nbsp;</small>
<% if current_user.voted_up_on? post %>
   <%= link_to like_post_path(post), class: "like", method: :put, remote: true do%>
       <i class="fa fa-heart fa-lg"  style="color:#900603;"></i>&nbsp;
   <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

--

Your JS should be as follows:

```
$('.votee#<%= post.id %>').html('<%= j render "vote", locals: { post: @post } %>');
// other line is okay
```

You'll also be best updating your `index` method to add an `id` to your `votee` div:

```
<div class='votee' id="<%= post.id %>">    
 ...
</div>
```

---

The problem is probably that the JS which is updating for all posts; the actual database might only be updated for the single post.

Comment: Thanks Rich Peck, It works for me. Actually `id="<%= post.id %>"` has done the Magic.